# React 16 upgrade fatal errors ag-grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-fiber

Has anyone upgraded their ag-grid installation to React 16 aka Fiber? I upgraded to react@next and react-dom@next, and instantly got a fatal error. My tool is closely based on the ag-grid-react-example, and the problem seems to be with cell editors. Anyone seen anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

we are aware of this in ag-Grid and plan to fix it soon (hopefully coming days), React Fiber changes how things are done underneath the hood, and the pattern we use to allow React components needs to be tweaked.

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting me know. So much for effortless backwards-compatibility!

Comment: for standard apps, react fiber is backwards compatible, however because we are a library, we are doing some none-standard funky stuff

Comment: Let me know if you'd like us to help test!

Comment: @NiallCrosby As react 16 is now released, we're not able to use it because of this issue, do you know when it's gonna be fixed? thanks for your help.